# Cannot find OleDbConnection in tool box in Visual Web Developer 2008 Express

Tags: asp-classic

Cannot find OleDbConnection in tool box in Visual Web Developer 2008 Express.
I have imported it from "item", but still cannot find it in tol box.

Answer (score 0):

Are you creating Websites project or Windows Application project?

Some Website project tools might not appear on Windows Application project tools and vice versa.

The OleDbConnection is not available for Websites project because you specify the connection either through Webconfig and server code or use OleDbDataSource which will make connection to your database using **connection string**.